# How to print an object from an object array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, object

This is an example of my object array.

```
Ball[] Array= {BallGrid[4], BallGrid[5]};
```

This is how I tried printing it out but the output was `finalproject.Ball@1dcc2a3.`

```
for(Ball value : Array){

    System.out.println(value);

}
```

How would I print out Array[0] so the value remains "BallGrid[4]"?

Comment: You need to override `Ball` toString() method with the information you want to be printed.

Comment: what are you trying to print in the Ball Class

Comment: If `BallGrid` is an array, then `BallGrid[4]` is an element. Despite the it should be called `ballGrid` following Java conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size() ;i++) {
        System.out.println(value.getClass().getSimpleName() + "[" + i + "]");
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to override the `toString()` method in the class `Ball`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    ...
    return someStringHere;
}
```

where you return the `String` that you want to use to represent the ball.

**Note:** Assuming `BallGrid` is an array (because of `BallGrid[4]`), you should call it `ballGrid` following Java naming conventions. And as @mikeyaworski commented, `Array` should be called `array`.

Comment: He should also call `Array`, `array` @user3209055