# How do i print a list of strings to the console and not addresses

Tags: java, xml, list, web-services, soap

I have made a class and want to call getTicketsCollection() and have it display the output below to the console.

**My question is how do i make it print the listand not print the addresses(?)**

Here is the full method

```
public List<TicketInfo> getTicketsCollection() {


        Tickets Ticket = new Tickets();



          List<TicketInfo> tickets = Ticket.getTicketCollection();



          System.out.println("Company name: " + nextTicket.getCompanyName() + " Symbol: " + nextTicket.getCompanySymbol()


       }
          return tickets_today;    
}
```

and prints this to the console (class output tab):

```
 [WSpackageWS.TicketInfo@177bea38, WSpackageWS.TicketInfo@7f132176, WSpackageWS.TicketInfo@6bca7e0d]
```

Comment: you are printing getSharesCollection() but in the other method you have getticketsCollection?

Comment: overwrite the toString method in TicketInfo

Comment: Funnily enough, you've withheld probably the only class you needed to post - TicketInfo. Implement a toString method on that class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print an object from an object array in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200311/how-to-print-an-object-from-an-object-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is how do i make it print the list (the stuff in the
>   server tab) to the class output tab (and not print the addresses(?)

It is very obvious, you are getting below output in server console tab, because that code is executed at server and your are printing each member of `TicketInfo` class.

```
Info: 
Company name: Microsoft Symbol: Frog Currency: GBP Available tickets: 625 
Value per share: 500 DateOLU: 04/04/2017
```

This isn't happening client side code, because you are trying to print the object without overriding `toString`.

So, there are couple of things :

1. You need to show the implementation of `getSharesCollection()` method, which seems to be returning `List`, but can't tell until you share the implementation.
2. Override `toString ()` method by adding following code

   ```
   public String toString ()
   {
       return "Company name: " + nextTicket.getCompanyName() + " Symbol: " + nextTicket.getCompanySymbol() + " Currency: " + nextTicket.getCurrency()
             + " Available shares: " + getAvailableShares() + " Value per share: " + getValuePerShare()
             + " DateOLU: " + getDateOLU();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks solved my problem.Also thanks to everyone else who took the time to comment!

Comment: not sure if you'll be able to assist me with this. But TicketInfo is a generated java-ws class. (From a wsdl file/xsd schema) When i overide the toString method everything works fine. However, when i recompile my project, the changes to the class revert. Any ideas? @Ravi

Comment: @j.piggens You are contradicting your statement, you are saying **When i overide the toString method everything works fine**, you have compiled and tested. Now, you are saying **when i recompile my project, the changes to the class revert** how it can be possible. You are doing something wrong then.

Answer (score 0):

Where you use `System.out.println(getSharesCollection());` you are calling the `toString()` method on the `List`.

This is what gives you the `[WSpackageWS.TicketInfo@177bea38, ...]` output. The `@177bea38` is a hashcode which is the default `toString()` implementation (for your `TicketInfo` class).

In order to display the output properly you need to extract the data needed from your `TicketInfo` class.

The best way to do that is to implement (and Override) the toString() method in `TicketInfo`. You can use the lines from the `System.out.println` in your `getTicketsCollection()` method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Write now the hash code of the objects is getting printed, because System.out.println(object) calls the toString() of the class whose object you want to print. By default, the toString() of the java.lang.Object class is called. To change that, override the toString() of the class whose object you want to print..
Hope it helps..